# IRAF fitsparams task deletes only the leftmost point

Tags: linux, plot, iraf

I am using IRAF on ubuntu 16.04 and a task called fitparams in the
photcal.fitparams package will not let me delete the points close to the cursor. It deletes the left-most point independent of the cursor position.
I can't find help anywhere in this regard. Can someone here help with IRAF ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this problem finally. It was a 32bit vs 64bit issue for IRAF. I had to download the 32bit libraries for this package and restart IRAF session.